# Cannot create connection to the Lob system.Connecting SQL server to sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013

I want to display data from a table in SQL server into an external SharePoint list but I keep getting the following error.

> Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System). Reason: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'